# ActiveAdmin "infinite loop": no error message, CPU & Memory usage increase, forcing to kill & restart server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I got this problem with ActiveAdmin. Sometimes, when i visit a page with, i suppose, an undefined variable, the server starts a kind of "infinite loop", displaying no error message and increasing CPU & Memory usage until i have to kill it.

Here is an example:

I got an Answers table, and this is a piece of code in answers.rb:

```
show :title => proc { answer.id } do
  panel 'Answer' do
    .
    .
  end
  .
  .
end
```

This piece of code doesn't work and displays an error: "undefined local variable or method `answer'"

I have to write

```
show :title => proc { @answer.id } do
```

to solve this.

BUT i got a Users table, and this is a piece of code in users.rb:

```
show :title => proc{ @user.name } do
  panel 'User details' do
    .
    .
  end
  .
  .
end
```

If i write

```
show :title => proc{ user.name } do
```

i get the issue detailed above, no error message and CPU & Memory usage increase.

**I don't really want to know why there is a different behavior between those two pieces of code, I would like to know how can i display an error message instead of getting no error and cpu / memory increase in such cases.**

Many thanks

Comment: Do you eventually get an error like "stack level too deep" in the log? Maybe do `require 'tracer'; Tracer.on` somewhere before the controller DSL code is run and check the stack.

Comment: I meant check the trace.

Comment: @GaryS.Weaver I used Tracer, it's looping on this line `#0:/Users/florian/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/result.rb:30:ActiveRecord::Result:-:         Hash[@columns.zip(row)]`

Comment: That is the code in A.R. to encapsulate the record coming back from the adapter. What DB adapter and version are you using? What do the User and associated models and related schema look like? Need to find the circular reference.

Comment: Do `rails c` and then in console `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('SELECT * FROM USERS')`. Does that work?

Comment: @GaryS.Weaver `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('SELECT * FROM USERS')`works fine. I think I found out what happens (thanks to you). I checked the log, there it is: `Started GET "/activeadmin/users/293600" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-14 11:07:48 +0100
Processing by Activeadmin::UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"293600"}
  (some usual requests)
  [1m[35mUser Load (7811.5ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" `. As you see, it's performing a SELECT * FROM users on the user show.

Comment: @GaryS.Weaver We got about 300 000 users. SELECT * FROM users itself is not a problem. However, based on the trace i wrote above, i'm pretty sure it's building an ActiveRecord object for each user, and this would overload the server. I think this is what happens, so it's not an infinite loop. But why this happens, and how can we prevent it ? No idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what was going wrong !

On User show, `a SELECT * FROM users` request was performed, trying to create more than 300 000 active record objects, preventing the server from displaying an 'undefined variable error' and making CPU and Memory usage increase.

For the same error on Answer show, i thought that a `SELECT * FROM answers` request was performed but error correctly displayed because the answers table had much less records. However, after a check, I noticed that it was wrong, no SELECT * request was performed.

Then I checked for differences between answers.rb and users.rb and I found this in users.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  scope_to :association_method => :scoped do
    User.includes([:current_device => [:current_device_config, :current_push_config],:current_web_device => [:current_device_config, :current_push_config]])
  end
```

After a check on Active Admin doc, I realized that it wasn't correct.

I moved it to:

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    User.includes([:current_device => [:current_device_config, :current_push_config], :current_web_device => [:current_device_config, :current_push_config]])
  end
```

Now, no `SELECT * FROM users` is performed and 'undefined variable 'user'' error is correctly displayed.

Thanks, you really helped me

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, sounds like a pagination issue. Try:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  paginates_per 25
end
```

and see whether that helps. There was an issue noticed in AA 0.4.0: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/996

Comment: We do have pagination gem. Indeed, it is all handled by ActiveAdmin. What I am saying is that when an exception occurs on the line `show :title => proc{ @user.name }` (see my post), active admin seems to launch a request on all records of the table. Here table users has more than 300,000.

Comment: Forgot about that. Should default to 25 also unless you have this bug in ActiveAdmin 0.4.0 which was fixed: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/996 Try adding `paginates_per 25` in your user model?

Comment: Edited answer to indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this and should point out that if you're using better_errors or any other tool that will dump the value of the variables in scope when there's an exception, you may end up with ActiveRelation objects being executed and dumped. In my case, millions of rows in a table that would be fetched in order to dump the value of the variable that really only contained an ActiveRelation.

I'm using Pow, and when this occurred, the ruby process would continue running until the machine ran out of memory and became unusable. Killing the ruby process was the only way to recover.

To troubleshoot this, I needed to run `rails server` the old-fashioned way and inspect the output directly. This allowed me to kill ruby immediately. It also would have been possible to inspect `log/development.log`.